Date picker in Excel 2016
I have cells in an Excel 2016 spreadsheet that are date values and formatted as dates.
Is there a way to make it so a date picker pops up when a user edits a date cell? That would encourage users to enter full dates, rather than just a year or a year and month, but no day.
Like this:

I've found a few pages online that describe different ways to add a date picker to Excel. But I suspect those methods are meant for newer versions of Excel; they don't seem to apply to Excel 2016. Unfortunately, I don't control the version of Excel my organization uses.

What ways have you seen? Have you tried them? If you haven't yet, don't assume they won't work, but try them and include information about how they don't work in your question.

As your screenshot shows, web excel does have a date picker (if you format the cell to date, then double click on the cell). For Excel 2016 the choice would be VBA or maybe an add-in, but this may not be practical. That may only leave data validation. Good luck.
